# how to implement unique date field in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I build an aggregator that pull posts from several platforms, Each post has some text and createdAt timestamp.

I want to be able to quickly sort the posts by time and to enable "load more" feature.
So I basically need to get all posts after certain unique createdAt timestamp.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get your posts like this:

```
var query = {
    createdAt: {
        $gt: YOUR_DATE,
    },
};
var options = {
    skip: OFFSET,
    limit: 10,
    sort: {createdAt: -1},
};
Post.find(query, null, options, function(err, posts) {
    ...
});
```

Now you can either change `YOUR_DATE` to set the cutoff date for your posts or you can change `OFFSET` in order to paginate the list. Notice that the `sort` is set to descending order by `createdAt`.